# Finding line style for ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, line, style

I am running ArcMap 10.6 and I need a line that I thought would be included in the standard styles. It is the line symbol used when a polygon feature crosses a line feature and you want to show that on a map without labelling both sides.

In the form I have usually seen it, it is simply a thin line with short lines on opposite sides of both ends at acute angles to the main line.

Do any of you have that in your style sets?

[Illustration of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l8El.png)

I want to create this using the drawing tool. I would probably then convert it to a feature.

How difficult is it to create new symbols for repeated use?

Comment: Could you show us what it looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of the symbol existing in Arc. However you can make it yourself and then add it to the standard style sheet. It is a bit tricky, but not impossible.

To make the line as you have shown in the link:

Open the "Symbol Selector" for any line feature. You can even draw a graphic line and then select to change the symbology. Select a Line Symbol - Major Road - as an example and then choose to "Edit Symbol..."

Under Properties make sure you have "Cartographic Line Symbol" selected, and choose the line properties tab.

On the left hand side of this dialog box you will see a "Layers" window, underneath the preview box you will see a couple of buttons - Plus Sign, Cross, Up and Down Arrows. These control the layers in your symbology. The best way to get the symbol you want would be to create your own layered symbology. Clich the plus button twice to add two new layers.

In the layers window you will see three lines. Click the Top line and then Under the "Line Properties" Tab, select the arrow pointing to the left, and the the "Properties" button. In the new window click the "Symbol" button, then the "Edit Symbol..." button.

This in almost like inception...

Under the Properties and Type drop-down list, select Character Marker Symbol and change the Font to "ESRI Dimensioning", Unicode 58 should suffice. Change the size of it 20.

This next part gets tricky, you need to change the Angle of the Line to 90, so that the line is flipped as per your diagram. This line is the line at the start of the line, so needs to fall under the line. You need to change the Offsets so that the line is moved to the start of the line. "X" controls the up and down, "Y" controls left and right. X = 5 and Y = -3 might work.

Hit ok, and ok, and check the preview on "Line Decoration Editor" window. If the symbols line up, hit ok, otherwise hit the "Symbol" Button and "Edit Symbol" again. Change the settings again to fit your needs. Once happy, choose the second line.

Again choose the arrow to the right -> Properties -> Symbol -> Edit Symbol
Change the Type to Character Marker Symbol, change the font to "ESRI Dimensioning" , Unicode 54.

Change the Size to the same as before (20), and the angle to 90.  X = 5 and y = -3

Click through the OKs and you will have the Symbol.
When you get back to the "Symbol Selector", click "Save As" and give it a name, it will be added to your default symbol selector.

If you wanting to create graphics from this symbol to convert to feature later.
Open the Draw Toolbar, Under the "Drawing" Dropdown menu, Select Default Symbol Properties. In the Line options, choose your newly created line symbol. Now every time you draw a line graphic, the symbol you created will be used.

Comment: Keagan,   I would never have figured this out on my own.  Thank you much.

Comment: @PhilFreeman Glad to have been able to help. It is a little long-winded but you can get some pretty good symbology up and running if you have the time to experiment. If you are satisfied with the answer could you kindly mark it answered. It closes off the question and will help people if they have a similar query.